# Call to window.close closes the session?

Tags: java, javascript, spring, session, session-state

I am having an Spring MVC web application. In application I am opening an new window using `window.open` on user click on button (`<a>`). When window get opened I am able to access session that is created by parent window, In new window I am creating another session using `session.setAttribute("examsetting", Setting);`.

On child window when user click on Close link (`<a>`) I have written following JQ :

```
 $("#closeBtn").click(function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            if (window.opener && !window.opener.closed) 
              {
            window.opener.location.href = $(this).attr('href');
            window.close();
              } 
              else 
              {
            window.location.href = $(this).attr('href');
              }
    });
```

This code will check whether opener of this child is still open; then load the URL on parent window if not load URL on the child itself.

When user clicks on Close link I wanted to close this child window (if parent is not closed) do some calculation taking values from session (which is created when child is open), But some client facing issue, where Child window get closed but on parent window error screen appears, I checked error log I found `java.lang.NullPointerException` on the line where I am accessing session (which is created when child is open).

I tried to generate the same scenario on my side but I failed, Is there anything Do you know about this? Is session created on child window get closed on `window.close` or some specific browser doing this?

Comment: why not pass the session info as parameters to the `window.opener.location.href`?

Comment: But session which is created on child is suppose to accessible on parent also, Right?